# How do I simultaneously run different scripts for NX projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-rendering, monorepo

It's obvious when I need to run `serve` for both client and server:

```
nx run-many --projects=client,server --target=serve --parallel
```

But what if I need to run `serve` for server project and `serve-ssr` for client project?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run serve for the server project and serve-ssr for the client project, I beleive You can achieve this using this command

```js
nx run-many --projects=server:serve,client:serve-ssr --target=serve,serve-ssr --parallel
```

Hopefully this will do the job.

Comment: This way it gives the `Missing required argument: targets` error

Comment: You can just add the targets. Sorry for missing it earlier, I have updated the answer.